Is UX StackExchange fading away?
I saw this post on HackerNewsletter asking about the once revered StackOverflow (SO) now losing a lot of it's shine:

Stack Overflow has been a cornerstone of developer communities for years, but recently, it seems to be losing its prominence. I’m curious about your thoughts on why this might be happening and what the future holds for this platform. Is it just AI or there're specific issues contributing to its decline?

Some of the comments from the discussion about the possible reasons read like the following:

when quality content contribution gets refused by the moderators it causes frustration
new users needing enough rep points to actually engage with it or else they just look for what they need and leave
closing topics too aggressively; very often in favour of topics that are too old, no longer relevant, or don't fully address the question.
for simple questions you can just ask ChatGPT.
closed as duplicate killed the site. it's important to not have duplicates, but editors got trigger happy with it, so questions that were similar but different were getting closed
for the same reason Wikipedia suffers: People who are really good at writing factual content / good answers are not automatically good at moderation, often they are even some of the worst people for it. Making the people who have the most points on a Q&A site your moderators was always a recipe for disaster.
Reddit and discord are way more friendly

So to summarize, I see some of the things that are happening over on StackOverflow also potentially apply to UXSE, mainly:

moderator actions having impact on the sentiment of the community --> If so, how can we do better (considering that the ratio of moderators to users is a lot less than designers to developers)?
platform limitations that don't meet user needs, whereas newer or alternate platforms can --> There is a process for feature requests, but I don't think this happens quick enough
use of AI tools as a first option --> I wonder how many answers point to UXSE compared to Quora or Reddit?
content curation and answer refinement --> I have personally updated some of my questions over time, but I don't think many people actually do this

Some would argue that StackOverflow has not faded away, but I am just curious as to whether some changes are needed because the platform no longer serves its purpose as well as it should.

Of all the reasons you've listed I think it's A.I. that is the biggest contributor to this situation here, and other Q&A sites.
It's twofold:

As you say, people can just ask AI for the answer to their question.
For people who still use these sites, there will be people who just use AI to create the answers to the questions anyway (and we know this is happening already).

This is probably a bigger problem for 'objective' sites like StackOverflow where a solution can have an objectively correct answer. Which AI is pretty good at solving already. More subjective sites such as UX.SE is (a bit) different.
It'll get to the point (perhaps we're already there) where being able to determine what answers are 'real' and which are AI will be indistinguishable. At which point, what purpose is this site serving beyond historical archive (which ironically, will already have been used to train the very AI that we're talking about)?
Does that mean changes are needed? I'm not sure what changes could be made that would still keep the site within the remit it was designed for - a repository for UX problems and their informed solutions.
Perhaps a more discussion based approach could work. But then we know as UX professionals that people don't actually like reading content online, so the longer and more discussion-y posts get the fewer people will read any of it.
Maybe it's just reaching the end of its natural life. Like Geocities, Altavista... or Google.
But at the moment it's still useful. The questions and answers have been upvoted by real people who agree with the content for real reasons. And while that's still the case I think the site is still of a lot of use. Real problems described by real people, with real people proposing real solutions.
Until that is no longer the case, I think the StackExchange network is still useful and relevant.

"a bigger problem for 'objective' sites like StackOverflow"… I'd bet a lot of the traffic here comes from SO users (through avenues like the HNQ) so anything affecting SO will probably directly affect smaller sites like this.
